# Comodo Antivirus - Free antivirus for commercial use

Tags: anti-virus

has anyone had any experience with Comodo Antivirus? Normally things are not free for commercial use unless you go down the open source way.

I would like to know iof anyone has deploy this antivirus across their network succesfully and how good it is? (all of our computers down here are Win Xp - SP2)

Thanks

Nico

Comment: How many computers are you talking about?

Comment: About 200.. when i first started the company was just a workgroup with a few linux servers for file sharing. Now we have got more windows servers than linux and a domain where all the computers are connected to.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used the product, but after looking at their site, I'd hazard a guess that you're not going to have the best time centrally deploying and managing that product. If you have a very small number of client computers you might "break even" on the amount of time you're going to spend tending to the product versus the cost of buying something that can be centrally deployed, upgraded, and managed.

Basically, you're going to pay for an antivirus product either in licensing fees or in your sweat and toil. (*smile*)

As an aside: If your users are running as "Administrator", you will get a "return on investment" from getting them to run as limited users. Many viruses, worms, etc, are severely hampered in their ability to "get things done" by a user who is running with a limited user account. You'll get some benefit just by doing that, even if you don't end up deploying anti-virus software.

Comment: If i present a proposition to my boss to buy licenses for an antivirus program and he knows there is a free version "that will only cost my sweat and toil"... then, unfortunatley, i now wich one they are going to go for.

In a sales environment company, the tech department is seen as an expense, because we dont generate money. Even when we get current prices to be reviewed and lowered, we are still not making money but spending less. They wont understand untill a virus finally hits the network.. touch wood it wont.

Comment: Yeah-- I've worked for companies who are like that (pulling all nighters to run cabling because professional installers are too expensive, etc). I highly recommend building your skills and looking for greener pastures.  *smile*

Comment: It all depends how you present your proposition to your boss.  A free anti-virus product may not only cost your sweat and toil, but if it isn't centrally managed, the sweat and toil of the other 199 people who run it, including your boss.  Plus, I doubt that Comodo will  plug into your mail server, or run on your Linux file servers.  In which case you will probably be paying to run another AV on those.  Present a total cost of ownership case for your preferred solution, if he throws Comodo onto the pitch, do a TCO of that and compare.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used the Comodo Antivirus, but I used to be a big fan of their firewall. I stopped using it when I ran into compatibility issues with our Cisco VPN software. The compatibility problem was severe enough to crash my laptop repeatedly. If you test it out and do not have any compatibility issues, it should be a good solution.

Since you have 200 clients, I would recommend that you use a centrally managed system. [Comodo Endpoint Security Manager](http://enterprise.comodo.com/security-solutions/endpoint-security/endpoint-security-manager/) provides a central console to administrate their antivirus and firewall software. However, I think there is a cost for licenses after the first five.

Answer (score 1):

We used Comodo (formerly Trustix) firewall at work, but the licensing was a bitch. Sure it was free, but it stopped working if you didn't renew the license yearly.  I'd rather pay more for a better license-scheme tbh.

Don't know if it applies to their AV software though, but it's a thing to keep in mind. Especially if you need to upgrade licenses on 200 computers every year..

Answer (score 0):

I tried Comodo's free products a few years back on my personal and it was a horrid experience caused the software caused many problems on my XP box, perhaps they have cleaned up their act but surely there are far better solutions out there.